# update rest url on application exit (Android & iOS)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xcode, ios5

We developing Android & iOS application. We need to update a REST URL every time when user exiting from application or when click iOS or Android home button.

is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: just start a service when you come out of your app, this can be done in android. don't know about ios

Comment: store your URL to `SharedPreferences`  and on `onDestroy()` method of the `Activity` check if its same or not and change it

Comment: thank you and working for android. Any solution for iOS ??

Answer (score 0):

in Android,override the method 'onDestroy()' of an Activity and make the code to change the URL there.

The method onDestroy invoked everytime when the user exiting from that activity.
in your case overide the onDestroy method of your last Activity or where the user exiting activity.

Answer (score 0):

use AlarmManager and the JobScheduler for doing task in background after exiting from your app

this link will help you 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html